# How to add new element to list in a map?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Map<DateTime, List<CleanCalendarEvent>> events = {};

example:

 DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day): [
      CleanCalendarEvent('Event A',
          startTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day, 10, 0),
          endTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day, 12, 0),
          description: 'A special event',
          color: Colors.orangeAccent),
    ],
    DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day + 2):
        [
      CleanCalendarEvent('Event B',
          startTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day + 2, 10, 0),
          endTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day + 2, 12, 0),
          color: Colors.orange),
      CleanCalendarEvent('Event C',
          startTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day + 2, 14, 30),
          endTime: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
              DateTime.now().day + 2, 17, 0),
          color: Colors.pink),
    ],
}
```

In this Map, I want to check if the Date time object I'm getting already exists or not.
If it does then add CleanCalendarEvent to the list of that particular DateTime object in the map.
and if it doesn't then add a new key-value pair of DateTime and List.

**Here's my approach but it isn't working**

```
if (events.containsKey(DateTime(date2.year, date2.month, date2.day))) {
        events[DateTime(date2.year, date2.month, date2.day)]!.add(
            CleanCalendarEvent('BookingText',
                startTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 10, 0),
                endTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 12, 0),
                description: 'A special event',
                color: Colors.orangeAccent));
      } else {
        events[DateTime(date2.year, date2.month, date2.day)] = [
          CleanCalendarEvent('BookingText',
              startTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 10, 0),
              endTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 12, 0),
              description: 'A special event',
              color: Colors.orangeAccent)
        ];
      }
```

Comment: This would be simple using a Map.update( ... ifAbsent: ...)

Answer (score 0):

This works in dartpad - I took your code and just simplified it a bit. Not sure where you have the issue.

```
Map<DateTime, List<String>> events = {};

void addMapValue(DateTime d, String value) {
  if (events.containsKey(d)) {
        events[d]!.add(value);
      } else {
        events[d] = [value];
      }
}

void main() {


  events[DateTime(2022,6,20)]=['a'];
  events[DateTime(2022,6,21)]=['b'];
  events[DateTime(2022,6,22)]=['c'];
  
  addMapValue(DateTime(2022,6,20), 'x');
  addMapValue(DateTime(2022,6,30), 'y');

  
  print(events);
  
  
  
}
```

Output is:

```
{
   2022-06-20 00:00:00.000: [a, x], 
   2022-06-21 00:00:00.000: [b], 
   2022-06-22 00:00:00.000: [c],
   2022-06-30 00:00:00.000: [y]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer, instead of passing a new obj of DateTime now I'm passing date**

```
if (events.containsKey(date2)) {
        events[date2]!.add(CleanCalendarEvent('BookingText',
            startTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 10, 0),
            endTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 12, 0),
            description: 'A special event',
            color: Colors.orangeAccent));
      } else {
        events[date2] = [
          CleanCalendarEvent('BookingText',
              startTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 10, 0),
              endTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1, 12, 0),
              description: 'A special event',
              color: Colors.orangeAccent)
        ];
      }
```